# Can anyone tell me how this piece of code works?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
void print_reverse(char *s)
{
    size_t len=strlen(s);
    char *t=s+len-1;
    printf("%s %s\n",t,s);
    while(t>=s){
        printf("%c",*t);
        t=t-1;
    }
    puts("");
}
int main(){
    print_reverse("Hello");

}
```

Can anyone tell how `char *t=s+len-1;` and `while(t>=s)` works. I cant understand how a number can be added to pointer and how the pointers are compared in while loop. This program is for reversing a string in c.

Comment: Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Debugging a program is a way to understand it. Read also a good book about C programming, and look also into some [C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Comment: It should not work because the loop is iterating in the wrong direction. Whilst it is legal to compare a pointer that is just above an array bound, a pointer just below the array is not.

Answer (score 1):

Lets do this line by line:

```
print_reverse("Hello");
void print_reverse(char *s)
```

Now `s` points to a string that contains:

```
- - ----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---- - -
        |  H |  e |  l |  l |  o | \0 |
- - ----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---- - -
           ^
           s
```

That last character is called the string "NUL" terminator because "NUL" is the name of the character with ASCII value zero (all ASCII values that are not printable have three letter names).

```
    size_t len=strlen(s);
```

Now `len` has a value of five.  Notice it does not include the "NUL" terminator so even though the string takes 6 bytes the length is five.

```
    char *t=s+len-1;
```

Now `t` has a value of s+4.  If you count the memory locations this is what you get:

```
- - ----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---- - -
        |  H |  e |  l |  l |  o | \0 |
- - ----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---- - -
           ^                   ^
           s                   t
```

Note that `s+strlen(s)` would point to the "NUL" terminator.

```
    printf("%s %s\n",t,s);
```

That printf should print `Hello o`

```
    while(t>=s)
```

This while loop will continue as long as `t>=s` which means it will do the body of the loop for every character, including the one where `s` is pointing.

```
        printf("%c",*t);
```

This prints the contents of the memory that t is pointing at.  It starts with the `o` and continues backwards towards the `H`.

```
        t=t-1;
```

That the part that moves t backwards.  Eventually t will be past s and then the loop will end.  When the loop finishes it will look like this:

```
- - ----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---- - -
        |  H |  e |  l |  l |  o | \0 |
- - ----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---- - -
      ^    ^
      t    s
```

Then there is this one final line:

```
    puts("");
```

That prints an empty string and a final linefeed - there wasn't a linefeed in the string but we needed one so this is a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

### Pointer Arithmetic

When a pointer points into an array, adding integers to the pointer or subtracting integers from the pointer moves the pointer back and forth within the array.

This function should be passed a `char *s` that points to a string, which is an array of characters ending in a null character (`'\0'`). Then  `size_t len = strlen(s);` sets `len` to the size of this string, and `char *t = s+len-1;` sets `t` to point to the last character before the null character.

Then, in the loop `t=t-1;` moves `t` backward.

Unfortunately, this loop uses `t>=s` as its control condition. This is intended to stop when `t` has been moved to the character before `s`, meaning it has gone back before the start point. However, the C standard only defines pointer arithmetic for elements within the array plus a special position at the end of the array. If this function is passed an `s` that points to the beginning of an array, then the loop will eventually make `t` point before the array, and the C standard does not define the resulting behavior.

### Other Things to Know About Pointer Arithmetic

Any object may be treated as an array of one element. If you have some type `T` and some object `T x;`, you may set a pointer `T *p = &x;`, and then it is allowed to advance the pointer by one element, `p = p+1;`. Dereferencing that pointer with `*p` is not defined, but you can compare it, as in `&x == p`, or you can subtract one from it.

If `print_reverse` were passed a pointer into an array beyond the beginning, then its loop would be okay. However, that is now how it is used in the example code; `print_reverse("Hello");` is not good code.

Any object may be treated as an array of characters. You can convert a pointer to any object to a pointer to `unsigned char` and then examine the bytes that make up an object. This is used for special purposes. You should not use it in general code while you are learning C, but you should be aware it exists.